# Do I need to sanitize php code im fetching from files?

Tags: php, security

I am using ajax and php for my current application right now. I give an action for each ajax request I make. I know that I can just give different urls to each individual request, but I want all my actions to be in one file. However, I want the one file to catch every file in a specific directory get the action from there and put it in the main file. So I would loop each individual file and fetch the content in them.

---

The code I'm using is the following:

```
public function fetchActions() {
    $output = "";
    $actions = glob("actions/*");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count(glob('actions/*')); $i++) {
        $output .= file_get_contents($actions[$i]) . " ";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

---

In the file I'm calling this I'm using:

```
echo eval($methods->fetchActions());
```

---

**EDIT: The reason why I'm asking is because I heard eval() function shouldn't really be used unless necessary. They also said if I use the eval() function I should sanitize the code before eval() the code.**

Comment: If those files are PHP files, then you should just use `include`,  or `require` instead. You can also just do `count($actions)` instead of running `glob()` twice

Comment: Can I ask how exactly would we do this? I'd have to loop all the requires, so I'm confused.

Comment: Just change your `$output .= file_get_contents(...)` to `require $actions[i];`. But honestly, this is a very weird way of including code. Why not just have the `include/require`'s in the top of the file and be done with it? If you add a new file, add an include/require. Or even better, only include the files you actually need for a specific action instead of every file

Comment: I think what you want is so called url routing.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson is there any problem with the code I'm using now?

Comment: You're adding overhead and unnecessary complexity by basically trying to replicate the native `include/require` behaviour and loading files that you don't need. Use PHP's native include expression instead, which will do the job _way_ more efficiently to only load the code you need, when you need it.

Comment: If you have eval() in your code and it happens that your site is compromised then the attacker can place a piece of code to further exploit your system. (it is known as Privilege Escalation) - that's why eval() should be sanitized

Comment: ...I'm also not sure how you would even be able to sanitize the code you're now loading using `file_get_contents()`. How would you be able to differentiate between your code and potential bad code when you're just loading all files like that?

Comment: which is what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: If you still want to use **eval()**, then just do santization of `$methods->fetchActions()` , before you eval it. The command eval() is invented for developers to use , but just be careful (agree ?). -- there are many posts on the internet about sanitization, just try to find one suitable for your case.

Comment: @KenLee sorry but how exactly would you sanitize code you've received from a file do you have any videos that can explain to me how? I don't really get how you would sanitize code if it's code...

Comment: This is another area. But just give you a small hint about security :-  **everything should be denied except those expected.** So it depends on what you want to do . (what actually do you want to do in those files containing commands in the actions/* directory ?

Comment: @KenLee all the files in the actions directory are going to be actions that need to be handled so there won't really be anything unexpected in the actions directory

Comment: Every system has a scope. (you are not re-invented an OS , right ?)

Comment: @KenLee what do you mean by every system has a scope?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239177/discussion-between-yuuki-and-ken-lee).

Answer (score 0):

Never use eval() just use it if there is no other way, but for sure there is other ways. You have to break your head but is better than someone breaks your code and security.

Comment: What specifically do you mean other ways?